# x64 assembly printf call results in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm writing a very simple x64 assembly code example that seems to be correct logically, but results in a segmentation fault. All I want is to use `printf` to output a value stored in a register. So, I store a number, `25`, in `rbx`. I then `push` `rbx` to the stack as well as the `fmt` string (in that order). I believe I'm obeying the cdecl protocol for function calls, so what am I missing?

```
section .data
    fmt: db "%d", 10, 0
section .text
    extern printf
    global main
main:
    mov rbx, 25
    push rbx
    push fmt
    call printf
    mov rax, 0      ; Exit code 0
    ret             ; Return
```

For reference, I compile and link via `nasm -f elf64 main.s && gcc -o main main.o`.

Comment: How does your code compare with same in C, compiled to assembly output?

Comment: [64 bit calling convention does not pass initial arguments on the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) (but read the fine print). Also, mind the stack alignment. BTW, your code would crash in 32 bit as well since cdecl is caller cleanup. Not to mention in at&t you want `$fmt` to take the address.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/h9P5z4KGv compare

Comment: Need to put number of `xmm` registers used (i.e. 0) into `al` as well, as part of calling a varargs function??